# Merge parameters in function

Tags: javascript, html

I have several websites where pictures can be uploaded.

On click on a submit button the function "add" is called and the file extension of the image is checked (allowed are jpg, png and gif).

```
onclick="add('jpg', 'png' , 'gif')"
```

The function checks if the selected file has the right ending:

```
function add(extension1, extension2, extension3){

  var ext = $('#_file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  if($.inArray(ext, [(extension1, extension2, extension3)]) == -1){
  alert('Nur Dateien mit Endung .png , .jpg und .gif sind erlaubt');
  return false;
  }

});
```

I would like to "send" the endings of pictures as **one** parameterm, not as 3 parameters like above.
Can someone tell me how i can do this?

thanks

Misch

Comment: Send it as `array`.. `onclick="add(['jpg', 'png' , 'gif'])"`

Comment: Sending as a array works but i receive the alert, so something might not be good in the following line:  `if($.inArray(ext, [(extensions)]) == -1){`

Comment: `if($.inArray(ext, extensions) == -1){` will do ;)

Comment: Thank you. Tried for hours and tried with the array before but have not tried without [( )].

Answer (score 0):

instead `extension1, extension2, extension3...` you can access global variable `arguments` which holds all arguments passed to the function

```
function add(){
  var ext = $('#_file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  if($.inArray(ext, arguments) === -1){
    alert('Nur Dateien mit Endung .png , .jpg und .gif sind erlaubt');
    return false;
  }
});
```